# Notepad++ search LF with regex

Tags: regex, notepad++, lf

I need to find specific part of text that contains LF symbols, but I can't use \n because it is avialible only in Extended search mode (without regex). Is there any implementation of LF symbol in regexs or any hack in Notepad++? If no, can you recommend any editor that supports that? 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you be more explicit on your need. `\n` is linefeed in regex.

Comment: \n does not work with regexs in Notepad++

Comment: It does work, I'm using it every days. Where have you seen that?

Comment: Just verified that N++ 6.6.9 on Windows 8.1 x32 can use \n in regexen just fine.

Comment: The problem was in using old version of editor (5.9). In 6.6 everything works. Thanks for your feedback

Comment: To make this question appear answered, please create your own answer (based on comment you already posted) and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Just verified that N++ 6.6.9 on Windows 8.1 x32 can use \n in regexen just fine.
                    – Nathan Tuggy

The problem was in using old version of editor (5.9). In 6.6 everything works. Thanks for your feedback
                    – Владислав Божко